# How to lower beta to top aligned with other subscripts?

Tags: subscripts

In the below the top of the beta is significantly higher the top of alpha, how could I make the top alignment equal for the two?

```
\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \[ a_{\alpha\beta} \] \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say it, but I'm sure you don't want to do that. It's like saying you wanted to align the top of latin letters, which you don't want: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sQEQ3.png

Comment: But that's what I want

Comment: I want to use them as two connected indices, and care more about them being *distinct* "sub"scripts than about the text line looking even

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You do not want to do that.** And (as a copy editor and typesetter) I hope I won't ever get to process your paper.

It really looks more like that `\beta` is a subscript of `\alpha`, which is of course wrong.

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\lowbeta{{\text{\raise-0.55ex\hbox{$\mkern-1mu\m@th\beta$}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x_{\alpha\lowbeta}$

\end{document}
```

You can also try simply to lower the whole subscript:

```
$x^{}_{\alpha\beta}$
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about beta looking like a subscript of alpha; a good point, I'll consider not doing it anyway.

Comment: @Asagen My recommendation is `$x^{}_{\alpha\beta}$`, so the subscript is moved a bit down.